# How to get a Overlay while showing a Pop up Window in MVC3?

Tags: fancybox, popupwindow

Hi all my overlay function is not getting fired when my popup window opens..don't know where am i doing wrong this is how i am calling my popupwindow in my MVC Application..i am using Fancy box as my Popup window

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {       
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({ modal: true
     });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

**Edit**

changed the above script to

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {       
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({ modal: true
     });
```

Comment: you are using the same selector within two scripts .... the second overrides the first so the `modal` option won't work. What I mean is that you only need `$(".fancybox").fancybox({ modal: true});` ... and not `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`

Comment: @JFK still its the same...no overay

Comment: Could you show your page? (I suspect you have updated the js file and forgot to update css file)

Comment: @Janis i cant since its on my localserver....

Comment: Than how can we help? ... Try to download fresh copy and to replace all files

Comment: @Janis actually i am using Masterpage and Child pages has the popupwindow